# Touchaction Event firing twice

Tags: xamarin.forms, touch-event, skiasharp, touchtracking

I am working with the skiasharp on xamarin with TouchTracking and while trying to handle the TouchAction event in code, i noticed the event gets fired twice instead of once.

```
void OnTouchEffectAction(object sender, TouchActionEventArgs args)
        {
            // Get touchpoint location


            pt.X = XamDIUConvertToPixels(args.Location.X);
            pt.Y = XamDIUConvertToPixels(args.Location.Y);

            // Display point locations
            Console.WriteLine("location X: " + pt.X + "\n location Y: " + pt.Y + "\n");
```

So, this would inevitably display to the console twice. And this becomes more problematic if say i want to call a function of text-to-speech in here, then the speech gets repeated.

Comment: have you checked `TouchActionEventArgs` to see if the `TouchActionType` is the same for both events?

Comment: You can refer to this doc: [Touch Manipulations of skiasharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/transforms/touch)